# How to simulate a mouse click with touch data?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I'm working on a Qt5 application to attempt to make use of raw input data from a touchscreen because touch is not fully supported by my Linux kernel (2.6.32). I wrote a parser for the raw data coming from **/dev/input/eventX** because even though X doesn't support touch, the events are still there.

I'm able to read the events just fine, and wrote a wrapper called "TouchPoint" which contains the ID and (x,y) coordinates of each touch point, as well as a boolean indicating whether or not the touch point is currently "active" (ie: the user currently has that finger on the screen). **It's worth noting that I also output the number of points of touch currently on the screen, and the value is accurate.**

My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to accurately simulate a mouse click with it. With multi-touch events in Linux, each touch point is assigned a "tracking ID" when the user presses a finger to the screen, and when that point is lifted, an event setting that slot's tracking ID to -1 is generated. I use this change of ID from some value to -1 to indicate that a touch point is "down" or not:

```cpp
void TouchPoint::setID(int nid) {
    if((id == -1) && (nid >= 0)) down = true;
    else if(nid == -1) down = false;
    id = nid;
}
```

So to try and simulate a mouse click, I do this when a tracking ID event is read:

```cpp
else if(event.code == ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID) {
    bool before = touchPoints[cSlot].isDown(); // where cSlot is the current slot the events are referring to
    touchPoints[cSlot].setID(event.value);
    bool after = touchPoints[cSlot].isDown();

    if(!before && after) touch(touchPoints[cSlot]);
}
```

And then the touch method does this:

```cpp
void MainWindow::touch(TouchPoint tp) {
    if(ui->touchMe->rect().contains(QPoint(tp.getX(), tp.getY()))) {
        on_touchMe_clicked();
    }
}
```

The button does not respond to me directly touching it, but sometimes if I wildly flail my fingers around the screen, the message box that should show when it's pressed will show, but when it does, my fingers are always somewhere on another area of the screen.

Can anyone think of something I might be doing wrong here? Is my method of checking to see if the touch point is within the button's bounds wrong? Or is my logic for keeping track of the "down" status of the touch points wrong? Or something else entirely?

**UPDATE:** I just noticed two things by outputting the screen coordinates of both the touch location and the button location.

1. The digitizer resolution is larger than the screen resolution, so I needed to scale the X and Y coordinates coming from the raw events.
2. My coordinates are offset because they are screen coordinates.

**UPDATE 2:** I've now dealt with the two issues mentioned in my last update, but I'm still not able to figure out how to accurately simulate a touch/mouse event to be able to interact with the interface. I also modified my TouchPoint class to have a boolean flag indicating whether or not the touch point was just updated, which is set to true when the tracking ID is updated and reset when an EV_SYN event is raised. This is so I can get the X and Y position events before creating the event for the application. I tried the following:

1. Using the QApplication class to post a mouse event to the QApplication::desktop()->screen() widget that has the position of the touch point.
2. Using the QTest class to raise a touchEvent to the QApplication::desktop()->screen() widget using the press and release methods for the given slot and position of the touch point and then using the bool event(QEvent*) method to try to catch the event. I also enabled the WA_AcceptTouchEvents attribute on the main window.

Neither of these works, as for some reason, when I have the **"bool event(QEvent*)"** method in place, the signal emitted from the thread reading **/dev/input/eventX** doesn't trigger the slot in the main window class. and I can't seem to find any other method to accomplish simulating the events. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that you sometimes get your message box "clicked" when your fingers are in a "wrong position" so it sounds like you a mixing global screen coordinates and widget local coordinates. It seems, in your `MainWindow::touch` you try to check if a point in global screen coordinates, e.g. (530, 815) is inside a widget's geometry (in its local coordinates). [QWidget::rect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop) returns internal geometry of the button (widget), i.e. a rectangle of widget's width and height, e.g. (0, 0, 60, 100).

You have to move the rect to a right position in global screen coordinates. [QWidget::pos()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop) returns widget local position to its parent. You can use [QWidget::mapToGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) to translate widget coordinate position to global screen coordinates. Then your rect is something like (500, 850, 60, 100) and you should get a hit and get your slot called.

However, better approach is to use [QApplication::widgetAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt) to get the widget in a specific screen position and generate a mouse click for it.

You can generate a mouse click for a widget by posting a mouse press and release to it, something like below:

```cpp
QPoint screenPos = QPoint(tp.getX(), tp.getY());
QWidget *targetWidget = QApplication::widgetAt(screenPos);

QPoint localPos = targetWidget->mapFromGlobal(screenPos); 
QMouseEvent *eventPress = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, localPos, screenPos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton,  Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::postEvent(targetWidget, eventPress);
QMouseEvent *eventRelease = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, localPos, screenPos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton,  Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::postEvent(targetWidget, eventRelease);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: However, I do get a segmentation fault when tapping outside the application from the mapFromGlobal() method.

Comment: 1) do you check targetWidget is not null, 2) you wrote something about screen resolution being smaller that "digitizer" resolution whatever that means... The code snippet is not supposed to be a complete robust solution but to describe how you can solve your problem.

Comment: No, it was #1. It's early and I was half-asleep.